# Split String by Double Back Slashes in Bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to split the string by double back slashes in bash and somehow it's not working.

My string is as follow:

```
abc\\xyz
```

My Code:

```
my_str='abc\\xyz'
IFS='\\' read -r -a arr <<< "$my_str"
echo "${#arr[@]}"
```

I am expecting that the output would be '2' as the length of the array would be 2.

However, I get 3 as a result and when I try to print the array values, I only get 'abc', and the second index remains empty. It seems like something is wrong with my code but I am unable to identify it.

Can anyone please help to resolve the issue?

Comment: `IFS` is not a delimiter string, it's a list of delimiters. Any character in `IFS` is a delimiter.

Comment: So `IFS='\\'` is the same as just `IFS='\'`

Comment: So you can't use `IFS` if the delimiter is a multiple-character sequence.

Comment: Use `awk` instead.

Answer (score 2):

If there are no spaces in your string you could use `bash` pattern substitutions to replace pairs of backslashes by a space and assign  the result to an indexed array:

```
$ my_str='abc\\xyz\uvw\\rst\\\012\\\\345'
$ declare -a arr=( ${my_str//\\\\/ } )
$ echo "${#arr[@]}"
5
$ printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}"
abc
xyz\uvw
rst
\012
345
```

Comment: This will fail when string contains spaces

Comment: Yes. I assumed there are no spaces but you're right, there is nothing about this in the OP.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have substituted backslashes with spaces in my string and used my code.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try to replace the backslashes on the string fist as showcased in [this previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/1068031/replace-backslash-with-forward-slash-in-a-variable-in-bash). However, this would be inefficient for very large strings.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different take -

```
$: my_str='abc\\123\\ghi\\\012\\jkl\\foo bar\\\\xyz'
$: IFS='|' read -r -a arr <<< "${my_str//\\\\/\|}"
$: printf "[%s]\n" "${arr[@]}"
[abc]
[123]
[ghi]
[\012]
[jkl]
[foo bar]
[]
[xyz]
```